# How send SMS without iMessage

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipad

I see how to send SMS with MessageUI ans it's work fine but I need send sms with an iPad cellular but it can't send without iMessage. Someone know if it's possible to send sms for all my phone numbers  ?

Comment: The iPad doesn’t support standard SMS.

Comment: I know it but can we use alternate services or an other idea ?

Comment: Only iMessage and not anything else

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it without MFMessageComposeViewController. Apple won't allow to send SMS without user interaction.

As per document

***You must not modify the view hierarchy presented by this view controller. You can, however, customize the appearance of the interface using the UIAppearance protocol.***

I've alternate solution of this, Alternative way can be Using web service API. Create a web service at server side that send a message to specific number(s) that accept numbers as parameters with request.(according to your requirement)

As using Web server or external sms provider can do it.

1. http://www.twilio.com/
2. http://www.nexmo.com/
3. https://www.tropo.com/